# JSON error on 0 prefix in array (but correct output in console.log)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using this:

```
var title = dataset[key]['title'];
console.log(title);
```

Output on console.log:
`Object {0: "Here is the title"}`

So when I do:

```
var title = dataset[key]['title'][0];
console.log(title);
```

Output on console.log:

```
"Here is the title"
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Comment: It works perfectly for me. No undefined. Check your code. What is <br>?

Comment: whoops... for the <br>

Comment: I've also tried [0] and ['0']

Comment: Please check your seplling?

Comment: Have you tried just this `dataset[key]['title']` ?

Comment: can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your error?

Comment: I think, your code works since i could see the output "Here is the title". The second error is happening somewhere else.

Comment: Found it, not every key had a [0]. I have to find out why this is added by using php's `json_encode()`

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your JSON structure. Try getting your result this way:

```
var title = dataset[key].title[0];
```

if you want to get the first element from your *title* array inside the *dataset[key]*.

Consider posting the actual JSON, or at least it's structure. It really helps solve the problem quicker.